# load mutiple version of php on apache on xampp in windows environment

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I was to load multiple version of php on xampp, and using ht-access add handler, so my one application should run in 5.3  php version using its htaccess and another application should use 5.4 php version.

can anybody please help me to deal with this?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have your main version of php set up with mod_php and run all of the others through fast cgi on different ports (i.e. 81, 82, 83 etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
The best method is to change the PHP settings in

/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

to reflect the new version of PHP you want to use

In my case I unpacked PHP5.4 to C:\XAMPPLITE\PHP5.4 and then updated key lines in this file such as:

SetEnv PHPRC "C:\\xampplite\\php5.4"

LoadFile "C:/xampplite/php5.4/php5ts.dll"

PHPINIDir "C:/xampplite/php5.4"
You also need to ensure that the correct version of php5apache2_2.dll is installed

To ensure this I copied the new version of php5apache2_2.dll to the Apache modules directory with a unique name, and then modified the configuration to match that:

copy php5.4\php5apache2_2.dll apache\modules\php5apache2_2-5_4.dll
and in the httpd-xampp.conf file

LoadModule php5_module modules/php5apache2_2-5_4.dll
```

Comment: i want to load multiple versions and want to use php versions using htaccess file handler. your solution will completely update the version, so at a time i can use only 1 php.

Comment: Hi amit You may take reference here ; I hope it will be helpfull for you

http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-install-and-run-multiple-versions-of-xampp-on-your-computer

Comment: no dear it says to run multiple xampp on one PC, that is not the correct solution, the solution which i am looking for is something similar to the latest cpanel which gives us, when you add file handler to htaccess you can mentioned php version in the same directives.